Docker Compose service accessible only via VPN
I have a Docker Compose service which I would like to access exclusively via a VPN tunnel.
There are two containers in the service: 1) "the app" and 2) "the VPN server". The app offers a network service on a certain port; it has no encryption, no authentication, no security features at all. I want the users of this service to be able to access it from the outside (the internet) in a secure fashion.
("The app" is an OpenArena game server, but that shouldn't matter.)
My initial attempt was to have a Wireguard container offer client IP addresses from the address range of the Docker bridge network, and then have the app container listen only on its Docker bridge address (as opposed to 0.0.0.0). This did not work.
If I was the only one using said service, I would simply use SSH port forwarding with the -L option. But this doesn't scale well for multiple users, and I don't need (or want) the users to have access to a shell on the host anyway.
I feel like this entire use case must be a well-treaded path with some obvious, canonical solution, so I'd prefer to go with something proven instead of trying to "roll my own". Yet I cannot find many resources for this topic. Any ideas?

The simplest way is to do this is to have the app container share the same network namespace as the VPN server. For example, if the app were an NGINX webserver, you could use a compose file like this:
# docker-compose.yml
services:
  vpn:
    image: procustodibus/wireguard
    cap_add:
    - NET_ADMIN
    ports:
    - 51820:51820/udp
    volumes:
    - ./conf:/etc/wireguard
  app:
    image: nginx
    network_mode: 'service:vpn'

If you configure the VPN server to use a WireGuard address of say 10.0.0.1, like with the following config file:
# conf/wg0.conf
[Interface]
PrivateKey = AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEE=
Address = 10.0.0.1
ListenPort = 51820

[Peer]
PublicKey = fE/wdxzl0klVp/IR8UcaoGUMjqaWi3jAd7KzHKFS6Ds=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.2

[Peer]
PublicKey = jUd41n3XYa3yXBzyBvWqlLhYgRef5RiBD7jwo70U+Rw=
AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.3
...

You could configure the app bind to 0.0.0.0 (both the bridge and the WireGuard interfaces), or only to the VPN server's WireGuard address of 10.0.0.1. Either way, all VPN clients would use the 10.0.0.1 IP address to access the app -- in the case of NGINX, browsing to an URL of http://10.0.0.1/ on a connected client would show the NGINX container's home page.
